# How can I visualize the logical partition size distributions in a container

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB database and I like to inspect or the logical partition size distributions in a container as well is the item sizes in partitions.

How can I Visualize (preferably) or get a report of logical partition size distributions in a container as well is the item sizes in partitions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Log Analytics / Diagnostics with [PartitionKeyStatistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-cosmos-db?tabs=azure-diagnostics)?

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where ResourceProvider=="MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB" and Category=="PartitionKeyStatistics" 
| project SubscriptionId, regionName_s, databaseName_s, collectionname_s, partitionkey_s, sizeKb_s, ResourceId
```